# Prevent loading template in DOM for initial loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to prevent template tags loading in DOM in Initial loading. I have some HTML tags which acts as a template. I need to insert that code once we perform an action, but initially it was added in DOM. I need to prevent for adding in DOM

```
<div id="template-1">
    Hello world Template-1 
</div>
<div id="template-2">
    Hello world Template-2 
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div id="CustomTempl"></div>
```

In the above code I need to render template 2 when we click the button only but it was showing page load. I need to prevent that.

In the demo bellow I have appended the template 2 in an `onclick` function and I formatted CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/qu9210wk/

Comment: Please take care to format your question correctly. It was pretty much unreadable.

Comment: To solve your issue it sounds like you just need to set `display: none` on the element on load via a CSS class, and remove that class when the HTML should be shown

Comment: use `script` notation for templates `<script id="tpl" type="text/template"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use templates way not use the [documented example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/#toc-using) like this:

```html
<button onclick="useIt()">Use me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  function useIt() {
    var content = document.querySelector('template').content;
    // Update something in the template DOM.
    var span = content.querySelector('span');
    span.textContent = parseInt(span.textContent) + 1;
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(
        document.importNode(content, true));
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>Template used: <span>0</span></div>
</template>
```

Comment: this is just example only... my question is prevent to adding of DOM element not hiding ....

Comment: That doesn't make any sens. Your options is to ether hide/remove a element after it is rendered or add it after the DOM is rendered by JavaScript. You can not manipulate a element before it is renderd.

Comment: A hidden element is not rendered for the user and takes no space on the page. That means you can manipulate it with JavaScript afterwards, but if the element dose not exist in the DOM-tree you need to add i before you can manipulate it. What I am saying is that $("#CustomTempl").append($("#template-2")); wont work if the element #template-2 is not in the DOM at the first place.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with a "template concept"